# lavalamp menu doesn't works in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am using drupal6

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://temp.lmfast1/Travancore/sites/all/themes/artsy/js/jquery.lavalamp-1.3.5.min.js">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://temp.lmfast1/Travancore/sites/all/themes/artsy/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://temp.lmfast1/Travancore/sites/all/themes/artsy/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
{

        $(document).pngFix();

    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".lavaLampmenu").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 1200 }); 

    });

</script>
```

I included the above code in page.tpl.php

put jquery.lavalamp-1.3.5.min.js,jquery.easing.1.3.js andjquery-1.6.1.min.js

but jquery doesn't works.nothing happens on hover of menu links

Answer (score 0):

change

curr = $("li.current", this)[0] || $($li[o.linum]).addClass("current")[0];

to

curr = $("li.active", this)[0] || $($li[o.linum]).addClass("active")[0];